# UI-Router Multiple Views Single Controller example

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i new in angularjs.i have same question [UI-Router Multiple Views Single Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708243/ui-router-multiple-views-single-controller.In) response it was stated

```
You basically need to handle this kind of stuff in some sort of provider (typically a service or a factory)
```

You can give an example?

Comment: You cannot share the same instance of a controller across multiple views because controllers are called with the `new` operator. The Idea to move stuff in `services` resides behind the singleton nature of that recipes... You can share the same service instance because it is singletone

Comment: You can give you an example?

Comment: Services are singleton, so, you should study the singleton pattern... and, of course, the object oriented programming.

Comment: if I pulled the data from the backend in the controller that I can not bring them to the service . The data will be tightened twice ?